# Data Transformation within a Tensorflow CNN Layer in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, spectrogram

I want to classify audio files using a CNN. Usually you can do this by converting them to Spectrograms and then training these.

This works fine and is described in Tensorflow's tutorial, for example.

However, I am now looking for a solution that does not compute the spectrograms in advance of the training, but rather computes them in the model itself through a layer.

Why this?

Because I would like to improve the settings of the Spectrograms by hyperparameter optimization. Or, ideally, the network itself should learn the best parameters.

I have built a small example. The first part is exactly as it can be found in the [Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/simple_audio).

```
import os
import pathlib
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

DATASET_PATH = 'data/mini_speech_commands'

data_dir = pathlib.Path(DATASET_PATH)
if not data_dir.exists():
  tf.keras.utils.get_file(
      'mini_speech_commands.zip',
      origin="http://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/data/mini_speech_commands.zip",
      extract=True,
      cache_dir='.', cache_subdir='data')


filenames = tf.io.gfile.glob(str(data_dir) + '/*/*')
filenames = tf.random.shuffle(filenames)
num_samples = len(filenames)
print('Number of total examples:', num_samples)
print('Example file tensor:', filenames[0])

commands = np.array(tf.io.gfile.listdir(str(data_dir)))
commands = commands[commands != 'README.md']
print('Commands:', commands)

train_files = filenames[:6400]
val_files = filenames[6400: 6400 + 800]
test_files = filenames[-800:]

print('Training set size', len(train_files))
print('Validation set size', len(val_files))
print('Test set size', len(test_files))


def decode_audio(audio_binary):
  audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=audio_binary)
  return tf.squeeze(audio, axis=-1)


def get_label(file_path):
  parts = tf.strings.split(
      input=file_path,
      sep=os.path.sep)
  return parts[-2]


def get_waveform_and_label(file_path):
  label = get_label(file_path)
  audio_binary = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  waveform = decode_audio(audio_binary)
  return waveform, label

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

files_ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_files)

waveform_ds = files_ds.map(
    map_func=get_waveform_and_label,
    num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
```

I tried to create a subclass of Layers that does what I want.

```
class SpectrogramTransform(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, fs=52000, nperseg=64, noverlap=32, nfft=16000):
        super(SpectrogramTransform, self).__init__()
        self.fs = fs
        self.nperseg = nperseg
        self.noverlap = noverlap
        self.nfft = nfft

    def calculate_spectrogram(self, inputs):
        _, _, Sxx = signal.spectrogram(
            x=inputs,
            fs=self.fs,
            nfft=self.nfft,
            nperseg=self.nperseg,
            noverlap=self.noverlap,
            mode="magnitude",
            )
        return Sxx
    
    def call(self, inputs):

        # convert tensor to numpy
        sess = tf.compat.v1.InteractiveSession()
        inputs = inputs.eval(session=sess)
        
        Sxx = self.calculate_spectrogram(inputs)

        # convert numpy back to tensor
        Sxx = tf.convert_to_tensor(Sxx, dtype=tf.float32)
        return Sxx 



test_file = tf.io.read_file(DATASET_PATH+'/down/0a9f9af7_nohash_0.wav')
test_audio, _ = tf.audio.decode_wav(contents=test_file)
print(test_audio.shape)

num_labels = len(commands)
    
model = models.Sequential([
    layers.Input(shape=test_audio.shape),
    SpectrogramTransform(),
    layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu'),
    layers.MaxPooling2D(),
    layers.Dropout(0.25),
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dropout(0.5),
    layers.Dense(num_labels),
])
```

There seems to be at least something wrong with the dimensions. But apparently there is even more wrong :)

But I don't get a very meaningful error massage either.

> Call arguments received by layer "spectrogram_transform" (type
> SpectrogramTransform):   • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 13654, 1),
> dtype=float32)

Does anyone of you have an idea or something similar already done?
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I think you need to use the `Functional API`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @djinn, that didn't fix my problem, but it's generally quite a good suggestion for improvement.

However, I have now found a solution by myself. I guess the problem was in coverting between TF tensors and Numpy arrays. Now, I do the whole Spectrogram calculation directly on the tensors. See [documentation of tfio.audio.spectrogram](https://www.tensorflow.org/io/api_docs/python/tfio/audio/spectrogram)

Here is the result of how I changed my class.
However, I also made some small changes to my dataset, but they are not that important here. But if someone is also interested in it, let me know and I'll add it.

```
class SpectrogramTransform(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, window=512, stride=256, nfft=16000):
        super(SpectrogramTransform, self).__init__()
        self.window = window
        self.stride = stride
        self.nfft = nfft

    def call(self, waveform):
        return tfio.audio.spectrogram(input=waveform, nfft=self.nfft, window=self.window, stride=self.stride)
```